# С начала 1990 года по некоторый день прошло n месяцев и 2 дня (n ≥ 1)

Tags: c++

С начала 1990 года по некоторый день прошло n месяцев и 2 дня (n ≥ 1). 
Определить название месяца (январь, февраль и т. п.) этого дня.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace  std;

int main()
{


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int conot, klk, nhot, vg, g, m, n;
    conot = 0;
    cout << "The enter klk mounts";
    cin >> n;
    vg = 1988;
    nhot = 1990;
    g = n % 12;
    conot = nhot + g;

    if (((conot - vg) % 4) == 0) {
        cout << "Год высокосный ";
        cout << "Прошло лет " << g;
        cout << "Текущий месяц в году" << n % 12;
        cout << "Стал год " << conot;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, вы слишком мудрите. Ведь все, что вам нужно - название месяца, а не год и т.д.

Прошло n месяцев. Один месяц и 2 дня - это 2 (или третье, как считать... что непринципиально - нужен только месяц) февраля. Пять - июнь. 12 месяцев - опять январь :)

Т.е. считаем просто `n%12`.

```
string months[12] = {"Январь", "Февраль", ..., "Декабрь"};
```

Тогда искомый месяц - `month[n%12]`.

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*